# Is there an app that will convert a movie to an image sequence?

Tags: mac-appstore, file-conversion, movie

Does anyone know a mac app for converting a movie (.mov) to a series of images ? I know quicktime could do this in the olden days, but that features has been deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, you still can do it with Quicktime Player. Download it from [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL923). I believe you can also install it from the Snow Leopard install disc. I'm not sure about the Lion install download. 
Open the movie and click File>Export:

[image]

Then you can select Movie to Image Sequence:

[image]

Set your destination folder and watch Quicktime Player do its magic.

[image: Exporting to image sequence]

Comment: Yeah, no problem! That's what Ask Different exists for.

Comment: It seems this functionality is no longer offered in the non-pro version of QuickTime?

Comment: For those still looking for an app, I created one such app because QuickTime took away the functionality. If interested, you can download it from here: http://download.cnet.com/VideoImageProcessor/3000-13631_4-75985051.html?tag=ext-gen1149%3Bext-gen1150 Disclaimer: 1) I am the creator. 2) I don't earn anything, the app is free. 3) The app is not under development anymore so there might be errors...for which I apologize.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -r 0.05 image_sequence%06d.png
```

-r 0.05 = 0.05 Hz = 3 images per minute. It sometimes includes a few extra frames from the start though. Without -r it saves every frame.

Comment: After hunting around for quite a while for an app that could do this, this was exactly what I needed.  Open source software FTW.  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called "movie2picture" in App Store.